# mysql query: use a list to fill in multiple placeholders

Tags: javascript, mysql, list, parameters

I want to make an update query in javascript to my database. For this query I want to update some 'order_index' values of a couple a rows. I am trying to do this with a CASE function and using variables for the `when ? then ?` part. however, the amount of row changes can vary so I can't pre-determine the amount of times I need to put `when ? then ?` in the query. My first solution was to make a function that will push `when ${id[x]} then ${index[x]}` into the query the right amount of times, but this is sql-injection sensitive. I tried to adjust it to the same, only then with placeholders, but now I don't know how to fill those placeholders, since it can be of variable length. Is there a way to use a single list of values, instead of multiple detached values, to fill multiple placeholders? Another solution for this problem is also welcome, if I'm not thinking with the right approach for the problem.
here is an example of what I am doing atm:

```
const values = [];
    for (let k in ids) {
      values.push(` when '${ids[k]}' then  ${indices[k]}`);
    }
    const query = `UPDATE table1 SET order_index = (CASE id
              ${values.join(" ")}
               else order_index
                END)
              WHERE other_id = ?`;
    connection.query(query, other_id, function (error) {
```

and here something I would like to have/try to make:

```
const values = [];
const when_then_values = [];
    for (let k in ids) {
      values.push(` when ? then ?`);
      when_then_values.push(ids[k]);
      when_then_values.push(indices[k]);
    }
    const query = `UPDATE table1 SET order_index = (CASE id
              ${values.join(" ")}
               else order_index
                END)
              WHERE other_id = ?`;
    connection.query(query, [when_then_values, other_id], function (error) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to use the generic SQL library and not something like sequelize? when you use dynamic queries it's generally a better option to use a library that is not just for plain raw SQL

Comment: I read that ORMs can produce insufficient queries and I prefer to see my query directly. However, this is not that a big of a must for me. I already have dozens of api-calls and this problem only concerns two of them. I'm not sure if it is a good practice to only use sequelize for two of them? I would prefer to have it in raw SQL, so I am hoping there is also a solution for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is possible to fill multiple placeholders with a single list, by removing the extra brackets at the parameter input. now it looks like this:

```
const values = [];
const when_then_values = [];
    for (let k in ids) {
      values.push(` when ? then ?`);
      when_then_values.push(ids[k]);
      when_then_values.push(indices[k]);
    }
    when_then_values.push(other_id);
    const query = `UPDATE table1 SET order_index = (CASE id
              ${values.join(" ")}
               else order_index
                END)
              WHERE other_id = ?`;
    connection.query(query, when_then_values, function (error) {
```

Of course there is still a `${values.join(" ")}` inside the query, but since it only adds a predefined string with placeholders, I think this will be fine (?).